# Hibernate in Win7 with.bat file. How to input y for hibernating and n for not hibernating?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have made a .bat file for Hibernating in Windows 7. But I want to instead 1 and 2 to use n and y. But errorlevel doesn't support letters. What I need to do?

```
@ECHO off
ECHO Press y for hibernate,n for exit
@CHOICE /C:12
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO two
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO one
GOTO end
:one
ECHO You have pressed "1"!
GOTO end
:two
ECHO You have pressed "2"!
%windir%\system32\rundll32.exe PowrProf.dll, SetSuspendState 0,1,0
:end
@PAUSE
```

Answer (score 3):

The default for choice is YN, so I don't know why you say it can't do it. You've told it to do 1 and 2 only.

Read help.

```
choice /?
```

The first choice is 1, the second choice is 2, ..., the nth choiceis n.

Comment: Thanks. Replaced CHOICE /C:12 with CHOICE /C:ny and it works. :D

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead of errorlevel:

```
set /p answer= Press y for hibernate,n for exit
if /i "%answer%"=="n" (GOTO one)
if /i "%answer%"=="y" (GOTO two)
goto :start
```

I hope I helped

Comment: I like it more than previous answer because I can input every letter, not only y or n :D and pc will not make beep sounds :)

Comment: @user320187 I am glad you like my solution